# Path integral quantization of QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, greens-functions

I am trying to derive the correlation functions in QED within the path integral formalism. As we know, the QED Lagrangian is given by
\begin{align}
            \mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{QED}} = \bar{\psi}(i\hbar \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} - m)\psi - \dfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} - e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi A_{\mu} \; ,
        \end{align}
where $J^{\mu} = e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi$ and the gauge field $A_{\mu}$ resulting from a suitable local $\mathrm{U}(1)$ transformation and the definition of the covariant derivative.

The generating functional reads
\begin{align}
        W[J^{\mu},\eta,\bar{\eta}] = N \int \mathcal{D}\psi\int \mathcal{D}\bar{\psi} \; \exp\Bigg\lbrace \dfrac{i}{\hbar} \int \mathrm{d}^4 x \; \Big[\bar{\psi}(i\hbar \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi + \eta \bar{\psi} + \bar{\eta} \psi\Big] \Bigg\rbrace \\
        \times \int \mathcal{D}A_{\mu} \exp\Bigg\lbrace \dfrac{i}{\hbar} \int \mathrm{d}^4 x  \left(- \dfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + J^{\mu}A_{\mu}\right) \Bigg\rbrace
    \end{align}
The path integrals over the fields $\psi$, $\bar{\psi}$ correspond to the path integral of the free Dirac field and I have seen how to solve this. For the free Dirac theory, i.e. without the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ gauge field, I would obtain the $2n$-point Green's functions $G^{(2n)}$ via
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        G^{(2n)}(y_1, \ldots, y_n; x_1,\ldots,x_n) &\equiv \langle 0 \vert \mathcal{T} [\psi(y_n)\ldots \psi(y_1)\bar{\psi}(x_1)\ldots\bar{\psi}(x_n)] \vert 0 \rangle\\
        &= \left(\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\right)^n \dfrac{\delta^{2n}W[\eta, \bar{\eta}]}{\delta \eta(x_n)\ldots \delta\eta(x_1)\delta\bar{\eta}(y_n)\ldots \delta\bar{\eta}(y_1)} \Bigg\vert_{\eta,\bar{\eta} =0}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, I do not know how to deal with the path integral of the gauge field with the Maxwell term in it. How do I proceed from here and solve the path integral over the field $A_{\mu}$ to obtain the correlation functions and subsequently the Feynman rules of the theory?

Comment: You need a gauge-fixing term  in the Lagrangian. Otherwise you cannot invert the differential operator in the bilinear term of the vector potential. This is a standard procedure discussed in all textbooks on quantum field theory and/or quantum electrodynamics.

Comment: Hi Chris Kindler. Welcome to Phys.SE. Consider the feedback from @Hyperon, and ask a more focused question.